# Hibernate generated wrong map for OneToOne foreign key

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

```
Student entity:

@Entity
@Table(
        name = "student"
)
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    @Id
    @Column(
            name = "id"
    )
    private Integer id;
    @Column(
            name = "name"
    )
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "id",
            referencedColumnName = "student_id"
    )
    private StudentCard studentCard;

.................................getter and setter below.........................

StudentCard entity:

@Entity
@Table(
        name = "student_card"
)
public class StudentCard {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    private Integer id;
    @Column(
            name = "balance"
    )
    private Integer balance;
....................................getter and setter below.........................
```

I have two tables created, student and student card. Both tables have a column named id as their primary key, but I am not trying to map them together.

I created a foreign key in the student card table where column student_id is tied with column id from student table. The owner is student card. However, after I created key and annotation, the hibernate still map to the wrong key when I tried to pull out the card information for each student.

For student table, the id is the primary key, whereas the student_id in card table is not. When I call for the student information in the controller side, I get a message of :

Hibernate:

```
select
    studentcar0_.id as id1_1_0_,
    studentcar0_.balance as balance2_1_0_,
    studentcar0_.student_id as student_3_1_0_
from
    student_card studentcar0_
where
    studentcar0_.id=?
```

and this is the wrong map, because I am not mapping student.id=studentcard.id

I tried to switch column/referencecolumn name and it gave me an error of Unknown column 'student_id' not in field list. so I am not sure what should I do at this point.

Comment: If you try have the same id for Student an StudentCard using `@JoinColumn(name = "id")` on the `@OneToOne` relation is not the solution. You shoud use @MapId. You can check this https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/.

Comment: I don't understand. What SQL query would you expect? This seems the query Hibernate uses to load an object of type `StudentCard`, for example with `StudentCard studentCard = entityManager.find(StudentCard.class, 5);`. What part of your code is logging the SQL? Nothing seems wrong from what you've described.

Comment: There are several examples in the Hibernate ORM documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one